# pyqt5 trying to use QGridLayout to organise my QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, and "Pop-up" QLabel

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to get the "Game Name:" (QLabel), input box (QLineEdit), and QPushButton on one line and the "Pop-up" QLabel) to appear on the bottom 
but am having difficulties with get QGridLayout to work

With this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle("Project PiBu!!")

        self.createGridLayout()

        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)

        self.game_name = QLabel("Game Name:", self)

        self.game_line_edit = QLineEdit(self)

        self.search_button = QPushButton("Search", self)
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.game = QLabel(self)

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 4)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 4)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_name, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_line_edit, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.search_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game, 1, 0)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.game.setText(self.game_line_edit.text())





if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'game_name'
```

Why?

have a feeling its something simple rather than something more complicated but maybe I'm wrong

Please help!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `createGridLayout` method earlier than you define the variables used in it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, 
                            QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
                            QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle("Project PiBu!!")

#        self.createGridLayout()
#        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
#        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
#        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)

        self.game_name      = QLabel("Game Name:", self)
        self.game_line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.search_button  = QPushButton("Search", self)
        self.search_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.game = QLabel(self)

        self.createGridLayout()                                 # < --
        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()                       # < --
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)    # < --
        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)                       # < --

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 4)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2, 4)

        # AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'game_name'
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_name, 0, 0)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.game_line_edit, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.search_button, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.game, 1, 0)

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(self.layout)          # +++ self.

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.game.setText(self.game_line_edit.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]